# Is it useful to have "add to favorites" button in the the search result?

Tags: user-expectation, user-research, e-commerce, search-results

I am working on an e-commerce website. I am wondering how useful it is to have "add to favorites" in search result?

Here are some example:

1. Etsy

---

In the search result, if you hover over the image, the "add to favorites" button appears over the images... however as there is no hover action in mobile devices, this option only works in desktops.

[image]

2. Kijiji

---

All images have the "add to favorites" button on them:

[image]

3. Amazon

---

There is no option to add a product to your "Add to List", from the search result. You would have to open the product page and then you can see the "Add to List" option:

[image]

4. Ebay

---

Some products have the "watchlist" button, but mainly you need to open the product page in order to add the item to your "watchlist":

[image]

---

Personally I never add a product to my favorites from the search result. The only time I use this button is when I open the product details page, read the description and decide if I want to add to my favorites. However most e-commerce websites seem to provide this option in the search result... but does anyone use it? or is it just an extra button on the page which clutters the design?

---

*Note I am using the term "favorites", however some of the e-commerce sites in the examples above have "watchlist" instead of "favorites".*

Comment: There is a mix of concepts: *Watchlist*, *Wishlist*, and *Add to favorites* (the question examples). For each of these three options there is a different answer. You should consider clarifying this so that both the question and the answer are clear enough for everyone.

Comment: Well, beyond the arbitrary name that each website gives to these terms, there is a specific definition for each of them. I think it would help a lot to use the correct definition here.

Comment: Danielillo is correct, watchlists and favorites are used differently. Favorites save items for later, watchlists imply watching price fluctuations on platforms where price changes frequently. Which is your question about?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "how useful it is?", the contextual answer is based on your users' answers; you need to ask them ('cause maybe the answer is different for other competitor products). But, if the question is "is it useful?", then Yes, it is useful to "help" them save things that they are interested in, from what they search, and as the above answers from others.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, there is no precise answer to your question, as the answer is highly context dependent, as Fathin has mentioned in his answer. Some of the factors that might influence its utility on your platform could be, the number and range of products and sellers on your platform, for example.

However, my best recommendation to you would be to park it for future scope if you’re merely building an MVP yet, given that the feature is not a show stopper for an e-commerce application.

Further, if you’re unsure of its utility on your platform, preferably pilot it with a subset of your users, and use Analytics to assess how often they interact with it. You can gain even more granular insights over time on how the users that prefer to use it, use it, by gathering qualitative feedback regarding the feature.